# Merge and aggregate result to original data

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataframe df, with 3 variables : id, category and quantity :

```
id category quantity
01 AB       235
02 BC       987
03 AB       366
04 CD       287
```

I want to add a fourth variable which is the sum of the whole category. For now, I do that like it :

```
df <- merge(df,aggregate(df$quantity,list(df$category),sum),
     by.x="category", 
     by.y="Group.1")
names(df)[4] <- "sum.category"
```

It works, but I don't find it very satisfying, there's probably a better way?

Comment: @Pascal : done, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another option with `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'category', we assign (`:=`) the `sum` of 'quantity' as the new column ('sum.category').

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,sum.category:= sum(quantity) , category]
df1
#    id category quantity sum.category
#1:  1       AB      235          601
#2:  2       BC      987          987
#3:  3       AB      366          601
#4:  4       CD      287          287
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1$sum.category <- with(df1, ave(quantity, category, FUN=sum))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tapply` to get the sums, then us a lookup table to create the new column

```
# use tapply to get the sums.  using with() makes the code nicer, IMO.
cat_sums <- with(df, tapply(quantity, category, sum))
# use lookup table to create new column
df$sum.category <- cat_sums[df$category]
#  id category quantity sum.category
#1  1       AB      235          601
#2  2       BC      987          987
#3  3       AB      366          601
#4  4       CD      287          287
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `dplyr` solution

```
df %>%
    group_by(category)                   %>% # Group by category
    mutate(sum.category = sum(quantity)) %>% # Sum by category
    ungroup                                  # Remove grouping
#Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
#
#     id category quantity sum.category
#  (int)    (chr)    (int)        (int)
#1     1       AB      235          601
#2     2       BC      987          987
#3     3       AB      366          601
#4     4       CD      287          287
```

The `ungroup` isn't absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the same merge and aggregate in a little more readable way.  Merging the actual df with result of aggregate on left outer join `all.x = TRUE` will do the job. I hope this is better to understand.

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(01,02,03,04),category=c("AB","BC","AB","CD"),
                 quantity=c(235,987,366,287))

df <- merge(df,aggregate(quantity ~ category, data=df, sum),"category",all.x = TRUE)
names(df)[4] <- "sum.category"
df

#   category  id     quantity.x   sum.category
#         AB  1        235        601
#         AB  3        366        601
#         BC  2        987        987
#         CD  4        287        287
```

If you still want a more easy-to-understand way, then sql is the best option. For this you might need `sqldf` library. We are doing the same aggregate and merge back to the actual df in an sql  way. Its more like a self-join thing. And the sql codes are quite easier to understand

```
library (sqldf)
dfnew<-sqldf("select a.*,b.sum_quantity
             from df a left join 
             (select category, sum(quantity) sum_category
             from df group by 1) b
             on a.category=b.category")

dfnew

# category id quantity sum_category
#       AB  1      235          601
#       BC  2      987          987
#       AB  3      366          601
#       CD  4      287          287
```